# HTML Grid does not copy/paste into Excel as nice as Table does

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to make my html Grid copy/pastable nicely into Excel? When I select a bunch or rows/columns from an old school `<table/>`, I can copy paste that neatly into Excel. But when I do the same thing with `<div style="display:grid"/>`, I do not get any grid/col oriented results. It's all one column.

Is there a trick to make Chrome handle this copy/paste action better?

Comment: This isn't a code question. Maybe try https://superuser.com.

Comment: The solution has to be code. Most likely the answer is that what I'm asking is not possible and i'll have to create an "export" feature. I wanted to avoid it - lazy programmer.

Comment: Please could you put a proper example of the code you are using into your question. The ode given is not legal HTML and it has not specified any column/row combination so we don't know what format you are trying to save.

Comment: Chrome is only going to provide the HTML you're copying. To my knowledge it doesn't do any translation or other magic. It's up to the _receiving_ software to handle it properly. I agree that it's hard to answer without a proper example snippet. See [ask].

Comment: Grids and tables aren't really the same thing even though they look similar. It's entirely possible to create a grid where the order of the elements in the source is different than the order of the elements as they appear. If your page is showing tabular data, it should be using a table. If it just needs a grid-like layout, it should be using grid.

Comment: This is actually a good idea.  I'll work on it and let you know what I can create.